# Use 110/120V Outlets, Receptacles and Switches in 220/240V Country

Tags: voltage

The outlets used normally in that country are exactly the same as what is used here in the U.S. - the only difference is they're 220-240V.

I do notice that the construction and connectors seem to be exactly the same - ditto with the amount, thiknesses, etc of the copper material, connectors, etc used... Even the AWG sizing of the wires are the same for the branch circuits.

Reason I want to use U.S. based 110/120V fixtures is they seem to be better built, longer lasting than the often China/Taiwan/Thailand sourced fixtures available in that country.

Is it okay to use U.S. type wall outlets, receptacles/fixtures and switches designed for 110/220V operation in a country where 220-240V is standard?

Comment: `I want to use U.S. based 110/120V fixtures` .... you can replace the wall outlets, but you will still get 240V from them

Comment: If you would tell us the name of the country, we could try to dig out the local electric code. Without it, the question "is it okay?" makes no sense at all.

Comment: The Country is the Philippines...

220-230V Standard 2-re with central grounding(I think).. The wall power outlets  there looks exactly the same as U.S. (3 pronged/2 pronged) but of course @ 220/230V. 

I've compared a US standard Wall Outlet with a  Panasonic Wall Outlet (reportedly made in Japan) that's certified for local use - and everything is the same - the amount of metal/copper used of course is more more the US outlet.

So does voltage matter if the total amperage rating is the same?

Comment: Again the idea is NOT to have 110/120V outlets/receptacles -- just to have better made, safer fixtures for feeding 220/230V native connections.

Answer (score 0):

The agencies who govern such things would normally tell you NO. However if the receptacle is rated for 220-240VAC with a UL/cUL/TUV label then it is ok.